# Q: How to obtain in chromium frames hierarchy (referrers) in browser process in IO thread

Tags: c++, chromium

I wonder what's the best way to obtain frames hierarchy (parent urls) for a request handled in browser process in IO thread, in particular in this handler:

```
int ChromeNetworkDelegate::OnBeforeStartTransaction(
    net::URLRequest* request,
    net::CompletionOnceCallback callback,
    net::HttpRequestHeaders* headers) {...}
```

Important is that the solution cannot be based on HTTP referrer header from the URLRequest/HttpRequestHeaders objects as HTTP referrer value may be empty in some cases.

One potential solution I found is to use WebContents API to build frames hierarchy, but that is not possible because:

1. WebContents API can be executed only in UI thread of browser process
2. chromium does not support blocking calls/messages between threads (in this case from IO thread to UI thread) - this can be hacked but that's not the point.

I wonder if anyone had this problem and what was the solution?